# Programmatically create script component of Data Flow task

Tags: ssis

How to programmatically create script component of dataflow task in MS SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Below given link contains the Microsoft hands-on lab to create a custom transformation component in SSIS. The document pertains to SSIS 2005 but the logic should be applicable to SSIS 2008 as well.

[`SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Hands on Training - Creating Custom Components`](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16454)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Code for creating a ScriptTask Programmatically.

```
Package pkg = new Package();
pkg.Executables.Add("STOCK:ScriptTask");
TaskHost th = (TaskHost)exec;
ScriptTask task = (ScriptTask)th.InnerObject;
task.ScriptProjectName = "YourProjectName.csproj”; // (or vbproj) 
th.Name = name;
task.ScriptLanguage = CS_SCRIPT;
task.ReadWriteVariables = “User::Var1,User::Var2”; //Comma separated list of variables  
task.ReadOnlyVariables = rvars;
task.ScriptingEngine.LoadScriptSolution(path);  // This method loads solution and builds 
task.ScriptingEngine.CloseIDE(true);            //  closes IDE and saves binary code
```

Comment: Script Components and script tasks aren't the same thing and don't have the same properties and methods available to them.